# Can I use the camera preview as a background for a custom keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-camera

I want to know if I developed a keyboard app for android, can I use the camera preview to be the background of my keyboard ?

so i can write messages while i can see what is front of me.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Not yet, my project postponded

Answer (score 0):

Inside FrameLayout use this camera preview library https://github.com/google/cameraview above that add your customized keyboard.

```
<FrameLayout
android:width="match_parent"
android:height="as you like">

<com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView
android:id="@+id/camera"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
app:autoFocus="true"
app:aspectRatio="4:3"
app:facing="back"
app:flash="auto"/>

<customized keyboard/>

</FrameLayout>
```